# Error: Command 'download_from_google_storage --no_resume --platform=linux* --no_auth --bucket chromium-clang-format

Tags: git, javascript, clone, comparison, fetch

When I try `fetch v8` or `gclient sync` I get this error:

```
Error: Command 'download_from_google_storage --no_resume --platform=linux* --no_auth --bucket chromium-clang-format -s v8/buildtools/linux64/clang-format.sha1' returned non-zero exit status 1 in /home/m
Hook 'download_from_google_storage --no_resume '--platform=linux*' --no_auth --bucket chromium-clang-format -s v8/buildtools/linux64/clang-format.sha1' took 13.83 secs
```

I searched a lot but couldn't find the solution:(

Comment: Could you link to the tutorial please?

Comment: @KNejad: in the bottom of the page it links to how to install `v8` : https://github.com/VarolOkan/libAIML